# Zynga FontLabel not displaying unicode character

Tags: ios, colors, nsattributedstring

In my iPhone application I need to display attributed text in a label, but I need iOS 5 compatibility.
So I choose Zynga's `FontLabel`

But when ever I tried to include unicode characters it shows only boxes instead of the character.
If I set normal text to the FontLabel it displays the correct unicode. But I need to display that character in different color.
For example like this

```
(red)This is up(red) (green)↑(green)
```

but it's not showing the ↑

How can I show ↑ and similar chars with FontLabel

Comment: What font are you using, are you sure it has the characters you're trying to use?

Comment: SegoUI also tried the sample fonts included in fonlabel sample project

Comment: Have you tried it with Helvetica?

Comment: Helvetica is system font right?  I have tried system fonts also

Comment: Try Zapf Dingbats font.

Comment: @matt I cant find needed chars in that font

Comment: Try Symbol font, it certainly has an up arrow.

Comment: @matt segoui has up arrow if I set as normal text it shows it but while setting zattributed text its getting boxes only